# AWS Lambda - error on importing pymssql (module not found)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Goal is to connect and query SQL Server instance via Lambda's Python code that has following structure:

[image]

I tried two configs but both leave me with error:

Option 1: `pymssql` listed in `package/python/requirements.txt`

```
datadog-api-client>=1.6.0
pyodbc>=4.0.32
pymssql>=2.2.2
```

Option 2: adding lib to zip file as shown [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/aws-lambda-python-ms-sql-server-the-easy-way-e7667d371cc5):

[image]

Both throw error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'function': No module named 'pymssql._pymssql'
```

Comment: Are you deploying e.g. from a Mac?

Comment: Deployment is done by Bamboo/Linux machine.

Comment: You can try to use a wheel file, get the link of the version you need on https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/#files and you can put that link directly in you requirements.txt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`impport cython` made it much easier then `pip install pymssql` to the directory.